# Ensuring class A can only be created by class B

Tags: c#, constructor, factory

I've read a number of discussions on this topic on SO (and elsewhere), without being able to glean a clear answer.

I want to ensure that a given class A can only ever be created by a specific class B. In C++, I'd make the constructor of A private, and specify B as a friend. Now only B can ever create A.

What's the idiomatic way of doing this in C#, if indeed there is one at all?

Answer (score 6):

You can use a *private* inner class for this.

However, this is of limited use.

```
class B
{
  private class A
  {
  }
}
```

Comment: If private class A implements a public interface, then you can expose that interface to the outside world.

Comment: What about a public inner class of A? ie

    Class A {
      public Class B {
        A MakeA(){....}
      }
      private A(){};
    }

Comment: @TomDavies - Such an inner class could be instantiated by other classes, it is just _inside_ the the outer class. See this related SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/337143/1583

Answer (score 3):

You can't use the C++-style approach in C#.

I've encountered this before, and I usually solve it by making the class A `abstract` (requires inheritance) and the constructor `protected` (only classes inheriting from the class can call the constructor).

I then create a `private` class within class B (called something like '_A') and inherit from A. (There's no additional code within _A.) _A defines a constructor which is public - thus visible to B (and B only, since _A is private).

Within B, you can create instances of _A and return them as A (via [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming)).

I prefer this approach to the public interface because my class B code file ends up huge if class A is implemented within it. That's just my preference though - others may have different opinions.

```
abstract class A
{

    protected A()
    {
    }

    /* implementation details... */

}

public class B
{

    public A GetInstance()
    {
        return new _A();
    }

    private class _A : A
    {

        public _A()
        {
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the last constructor be `public _A`?

Comment: @spender - Thanks, fixed. Haven't actually compiled this code - just meant for demonstration. :)

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that external code needs to reference `A`, but should not be able to create instances.

There is no simple way to achieve this.  If you make `A`'s constructor `internal` then only code within the same assembly as `A` will be able to construct it (without using reflection).

You *could* create an instance of [`StackTrace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.aspx) and check the frame at index 1 to see if it comes from a method of `B`, but this may lead to performance issues, and is kind of a hack.

Answer (score 1):

It's doable, but in a nasty way. Arguably more nasty then "friend" concept in C++.

You can declare private constructor and a static factory method where you would allow only specific type to call this method (by checking StackFrame).

```
public class Foo
{
  private Foo() { }

  public static Foo Create()
  {
    if(GetCallingType() != typeof(Bar))
    {
      throw new Exception("Only Bar can create Foo");
    }
    return new Foo();
  }

  private static Type GetCallingType()
  {
    return new StackFrame(2, false).GetMethod().DeclaringType;
  }
}
```